# How to combine two tables in a query

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have two tables. The first is *user*; this consists of *username* and *userid*. The second is *search* which consists of *userid* and *query*.

When I select the search table I want user ID to be replaced by username by taking the data from the user table. Is this making sense?

| userid | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | foo1 |
| 2 | foo2 |
| 3 | foo3 |
| 4 | foo4 |

| userid | query |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | blah1 |
| 2 | blah2 |
| 3 | blah2 |
| 4 | blah2 |

Is there a way to do this with a single query?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You are looking for an [inner join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join). This would do it:

```
SELECT s.query, u.username
FROM search s
INNER JOIN users u
ON s.userid = u.userid
```

Comment: Why would linking something easily searchable persuade you to upvote?

Comment: you took my +1 here for the tactical downvoting question ;)
but don't tell it to anyone because i don't know if it's fair.. ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT username, query FROM Users, Queries WHERE Users.userid=Queries.userid;
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. For example, why does it appear to be different from the accepted answer? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1141635/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.`username`, s.`query` 
    FROM `search` s
        INNER JOIN `users` u ON s.`userid` = u.`userid`
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. For example, why does it appear to be different from the accepted answer? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1141620/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).